# How do I center this image, get it above the text, and have it play together nicely?! (in ionic)

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to get the heart image to be centered above the title text and not "fall" behind it / get cut off. Please help!!!!!!

[Image of how app looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OaA7.png)
    
    
    
    
    Title

```
page-splash-page {
  .scroll-content {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
ion-img {
  margin: 30px;
}

p {
  color: #0054A6;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is my HTML code: 

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-img width="70" height="70" src="../assets/images/RACVD-logo-01.png"></ion-img>
    <p text-center>
   Title
  </p>
</ion-content>

Comment: Edit your question to include your HTML instead of putting it in a comment

Comment: Add your html to your question and make a working code snippet

Answer (score 0):

From the Ionic documentation, http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/:

> Note that ion-img also comes with a few more restrictions in
>   comparison to the standard img element. A good rule is, if there are
>   only a few images to be rendered on a page, then the standard img is
>   probably best. However, if a page has the potential for hundreds or
>   even thousands of images within a scrollable area, then ion-img would
>   be better suited for the job.

I would therefore suggest using a simple img for your heart image.
To center, I would suggest using the following:

In your html:

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="../assets/images/RACVD-logo-01.png" />
</div>
<p text-center> Title </p>
```

In your scss:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  .image {
    margin: 30px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
  }
}
```